# How to solve AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying out Harry's invisibility cloak but getting Axis error and the display it shows while I run the code wouldn't just go away! I mean it's already showing error and I can't close that display tab either unless I close the IDE totally. Putting down the code here. Can somebody help me figure this out? How do I solve this axis issue? I guess the tab's also got frozen for this reason.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(3)
background=0

for i in range(30):
    ret,background = cap.read()

background = np.flip(background,axis=1)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, img = cap.read()
    img = np.flip(img, axis = 1)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(hsv, (35, 35), 0)
    lower = np.array([0,120,70])
    upper = np.array([10,255,255])
    mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    lower_red = np.array([170,120,70])
    upper_red = np.array([180,255,255])
    mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

    mask = mask1 + mask2
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, 
                            np.ones((5,5),np.uint8))
    img[np.where(mask == 255)] = background[np.where(mask == 255)]
    cv2.imshow('Display',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k == 27:
        break
```

I'm getting error inside the for loop of the code, let me note the error notification:

```
     8 for i in range(60):
     9     ret,background = cap.read()
---> 10 background = np.flip(background,axis=1)
```

AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0

Comment: proper [mre] and complete traceback required. your code is broken. indentation is syntax, not arbitrary.

Comment: At this point `background` is a 0d array, a scalar.  It can't be `flip`, especially on the on nonexistent axis 1.  You start of defining it as `0`, obviously not a matrix.  You repeatedly set it with the `cap.read`, but aren't accumulating any results over the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works without modification on my laptop. Probably `cap.read()` returns no images on your system. You should always check the `ret` value to check if the `cap.read()` succeeds.

It seems you are using odd colour ranges. Shadows in my face are vanishing under the cloak. I tried with green colour only (hue 40-80) which works very nice.